# Test in app purchase on Simulator is ok but can not test on Device?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, device

HI I follow the instruction of doing In App Purchase from this site:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/21081/. When I test it on Simulator IOS 6.1
every thing run fine and this is the output

> 2013-11-06 16:34:54.302 LearnChinese[3821:907] Loaded list of
>   products... 2013-11-06 16:34:54.303 LearnChinese[3821:907] Found
>   product: TNY.coop.LearnChinese.BuyLesson Buy All Lessons 3.99
>   2013-11-06 16:34:54.303 LearnChinese[3821:907] Found product:
>   TNY.coop.LearnChinese.FreeAdds Remve Adds 1.99

But when I test on Device it show a blank View and this is the output

> 2013-11-06 16:34:54.302 LearnChinese[3821:907] Loaded list of
>   products...

I use Xcode 5, I also logout my ID in App store in Device but it didn't work. Any one know please help me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logout from your itunes account from setting->app store then check in app purchase

Comment: I did log out in appstore but It still didnt work :(

Comment: Ok ....sometime there will be delay or problem in response for product listing and make sure that the sandbox acc setting and also check the certificate in which you use the Device is register or not ....